# How do I calculate a point on a circle’s circumference?

Tags: algorithm, math, trigonometry

How can the following function be implemented in various languages?

Calculate the `(x,y)` point on the circumference of a circle, given input values of:

- Radius
- Angle
- Origin (optional parameter, if supported by the language)

Answer (score 651, accepted):

The [parametric equation for a circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations) is

```
x = cx + r * cos(a)
y = cy + r * sin(a)
```

Where *r* is the radius, *cx,cy* the origin, and *a* the angle.

That's pretty easy to adapt into any language with basic trig functions. *Note that most languages will use [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) for the angle in trig functions, so rather than cycling through 0..360 degrees, you're cycling through 0..2PI radians.*

Comment: Note that `a` must be in radians - that was really hard for me as a beginner to understand.

Comment: I've been trying to derive this equation for an hour now. Thanks. Who know the trig identities you learned in high school would be so helpful.

Comment: @Dean No need for extra brackets because of the operator precedence. When you have `+` and `*` like in those two equations and without any brackets you always go for the `*` first and then for the `+`.

Comment: @IsiomaNnodum Couldn't have been that helpful if we're all coming back here just to remember what the equation was.

Answer (score 56):

My implementation in C#:

```cs
public static PointF PointOnCircle(float radius, float angleInDegrees, PointF origin)
{
    // Convert from degrees to radians via multiplication by PI/180        
    float x = (float)(radius * Math.Cos(angleInDegrees * Math.PI / 180F)) + origin.X;
    float y = (float)(radius * Math.Sin(angleInDegrees * Math.PI / 180F)) + origin.Y;

    return new PointF(x, y);
}
```

Comment: Pre-compute the conversion factor so there's less chance you type the conversion wrong using hard-coded numbers.

Answer (score 18):

Who needs trig when you have [complex numbers](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/e_to_the_pi_times_i.png):

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI      3.14159265358979323846

typedef complex double Point;

Point point_on_circle ( double radius, double angle_in_degrees, Point centre )
{
    return centre + radius * cexp ( PI * I * ( angle_in_degrees  / 180.0 ) );
}
```

Comment: How does this work? How does it compare speed wise? Why isn't this more commonly used?

Comment: @MarkA.Ropper how do complex numbers work? - look up a maths tutorial or go from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity if you already know what a complex number is. It's probably not as efficient in speed compared to say implementing sin as a look-up table, but sometimes you are using complex numbers to represent points throughout to exploit other properties of them. Similar to using quaternions for 3D rotations, it's not really the speed but the capabilities they give you.

Answer (score 9):

Implemented in **JavaScript (ES6)**:

```js
/**
    * Calculate x and y in circle's circumference
    * @param {Object} input - The input parameters
    * @param {number} input.radius - The circle's radius
    * @param {number} input.angle - The angle in degrees
    * @param {number} input.cx - The circle's origin x
    * @param {number} input.cy - The circle's origin y
    * @returns {Array[number,number]} The calculated x and y
*/
function pointsOnCircle({ radius, angle, cx, cy }){

    angle = angle * ( Math.PI / 180 ); // Convert from Degrees to Radians
    const x = cx + radius * Math.sin(angle);
    const y = cy + radius * Math.cos(angle);
    return [ x, y ];

}
```

---

**Usage:**

```js
const [ x, y ] = pointsOnCircle({ radius: 100, angle: 180, cx: 150, cy: 150 });
console.log( x, y );
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kostasx/pen/vYOxwLd?editors=1010)

```js
/**
 * Calculate x and y in circle's circumference
 * @param {Object} input - The input parameters
 * @param {number} input.radius - The circle's radius
 * @param {number} input.angle - The angle in degrees
 * @param {number} input.cx - The circle's origin x
 * @param {number} input.cy - The circle's origin y
 * @returns {Array[number,number]} The calculated x and y
 */
function pointsOnCircle({ radius, angle, cx, cy }){
  angle = angle * ( Math.PI / 180 ); // Convert from Degrees to Radians
  const x = cx + radius * Math.sin(angle);
  const y = cy + radius * Math.cos(angle);
  return [ x, y ];
}

const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function draw( x, y ){

  ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
  ctx.arc( 100, 100, 80, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "indigo";
  ctx.arc( x, y, 6, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  
}

let angle = 0;  // In degrees
setInterval(function(){

  const [ x, y ] = pointsOnCircle({ radius: 80, angle: angle++, cx: 100, cy: 100 });
  console.log( x, y );
  draw( x, y );
  document.querySelector("#degrees").innerHTML = angle + "&deg;";
  document.querySelector("#points").textContent = x.toFixed() + "," + y.toFixed();

}, 100 );
```

```html
<p>Degrees: <span id="degrees">0</span></p>
<p>Points on Circle (x,y): <span id="points">0,0</span></p>
<canvas width="200" height="200" style="border: 1px solid"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

Calculating point around circumference of circle given distance travelled.
For comparison...
This may be useful in Game AI when moving around a solid object in a direct path.

[image]

```cs
public static Point DestinationCoordinatesArc(Int32 startingPointX, Int32 startingPointY,
    Int32 circleOriginX, Int32 circleOriginY, float distanceToMove,
    ClockDirection clockDirection, float radius)
{
    // Note: distanceToMove and radius parameters are float type to avoid integer division
    // which will discard remainder

    var theta = (distanceToMove / radius) * (clockDirection == ClockDirection.Clockwise ? 1 : -1);
    var destinationX = circleOriginX + (startingPointX - circleOriginX) * Math.Cos(theta) - (startingPointY - circleOriginY) * Math.Sin(theta);
    var destinationY = circleOriginY + (startingPointX - circleOriginX) * Math.Sin(theta) + (startingPointY - circleOriginY) * Math.Cos(theta);

    // Round to avoid integer conversion truncation
    return new Point((Int32)Math.Round(destinationX), (Int32)Math.Round(destinationY));
}

/// <summary>
/// Possible clock directions.
/// </summary>
public enum ClockDirection
{
    [Description("Time moving forwards.")]
    Clockwise,
    [Description("Time moving moving backwards.")]
    CounterClockwise
}

private void ButtonArcDemo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Brush aBrush = (Brush)Brushes.Black;
    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();

    var startingPointX = 125;
    var startingPointY = 75;
    for (var count = 0; count < 62; count++)
    {
        var point = DestinationCoordinatesArc(
            startingPointX: startingPointX, startingPointY: startingPointY,
            circleOriginX: 75, circleOriginY: 75,
            distanceToMove: 5,
            clockDirection: ClockDirection.Clockwise, radius: 50);
        g.FillRectangle(aBrush, point.X, point.Y, 1, 1);

        startingPointX = point.X;
        startingPointY = point.Y;

        // Pause to visually observe/confirm clock direction
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(35);

        Debug.WriteLine($"DestinationCoordinatesArc({point.X}, {point.Y}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = (int)(radius * Math.Cos(degree * Math.PI / 180F)) + cCenterX;
int y = (int)(radius * Math.Sin(degree * Math.PI / 180F)) + cCenterY;
```

The `cCenterX` and `cCenterY` are the center point of the circle