# How to find intersection point (CGPoint) between QuadCurve and Line UIBezierPaths in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, intersection, uibezierpath, bezier

I've a QuadCurve and Line drawn using UIBezierPath in my custom view class. How can I get their intersection point as CGPoint?

[image: Bezier Paths]

For QuadCurve:

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.lineWidth = 3.0
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height))
path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: 0), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width-self.frame.size.width/3, y: self.frame.size.height))
```

For Line:

```
let path2 = UIBezierPath()
path2.lineWidth = 3.0
path2.move(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: 0))
path2.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: self.frame.size.height))
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279999/finding-a-dot-on-a-circle-by-degree

Comment: @canister_exister, thank you for your comment but my requirement is of a curve. I tried to do the same with an arc but I'm not getting an expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your line is always vertical, calculations are quite simple: x-coordinate is known, so you task is to find y-coordinate. Quadratic  Bezier curve has parametric representation:

```
P(t) = P0*(1-t)^2 + 2*P1*(1-t)*t + P2*t^2 = 
       t^2 * (P0 - 2*P1 + P2) + t * (-2*P0 + 2*P1)  + P0
```

where `P0, P1, P2`  are starting, control and ending points.

So you have to solve quadratic equation

```
t^2 * (P0.X - 2*P1.X + P2.X) + t * (-2*P0.X + 2*P1.X)  + (P0.X - LineX) = 0
```

for unknown `t`, get root in range `0..1`, and apply `t` value to the similar expression for Y-coordinate

```
Y = P0.Y*(1-t)^2 + 2*P1.Y*(1-t)*t + P2.Y*t^2
```

For arbitrary line make equation system for line parametric representation and curve, and solve that system