# Find a point on a circle circumference based on degrees

Tags: tags, geometry, point, degrees

Let's say that you have a stick figure.  Let's say the stick figure has an elbow and a hand.  What if the stick figure wants to spin his hand in a windmill without moving his elbow?  If the elbow serves as the center of a circle, and the hand must always be on the circle's circumference, and I know the exact location of the elbow and hand, how do I move the hand around the circle's circumference, while preserving the radius (the length of the arm between the elbow and hand because it really shouldn't shrink or grow)?

I need to move the coordinate of the hand along the circumference of a circle, where the center of the circle is the elbow.  This is in 2D.

I have the coordinates of both points.  I can calculate the radius which is the length of the line between the points.  Knowing the circle's center and radius, how do I rotate the hand along the circle circumference?  I want it to maintain the radius, but change positions on the circumference.  Basically, it must act like it's hinged.

P.S: I had a picture, but Stack Overflow said I was too new... Blame Stack Overflow.

Comment: Perhaps answer to this question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839899/how-do-i-calculate-a-point-on-a-circles-circumference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic trigonometry says:

```
x = r * cos(a);
y = r * sin(a);
```

This does not take into account the rotation of the hand, just shows the point on the circle where the wrist will be.  Is that what you are after?

EDIT: Sorry, that assumes the elbow is at (0, 0) and x +ve is right and y +ve is up.

Given the elbow is at (ex, ey) then wrist is at:

```
wx = ex + r * cos(a);
wy = ey + r * sin(a);
```

If, as happens in browsers, y is +ve down, then subtract instead of add.

Comment: Worth remembering that typically cos() and sin() take an argument in radians. If your angle is in degrees (as the question subject suggests), you'll need to multiply it by pi/180 first.

Comment: Thanks.  The wrist was what I meant; sorry my question was vague.  I'll give it a shot, I don't see why it won't work.