# How to determine point rotate circle around 1 object in Box2d - cocos2d-x ver3.*

Tags: cocos2d-x, box2d

Sorry guy about last question.

My question:
How to determine point rotate circle around 1 object in Box2d - cocos2d-x ver3.* 
[image]

Comment: please elaborate on what exactly you need to know, the question is vague/unclear

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: are you clear my question? :)

Comment: I still don't understand. Do you want to rotate a point around the position of a given object, is that it? So basically you want to know how to get the position on the circumference of a circle with a given radius and angle? If that's it, there's plenty of examples here, for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335742/find-a-point-on-a-circle-circumference-based-on-degrees

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: similar but point and object are dynamically.I want to know about rotate full circle around 1 dynamic object

Comment: it's still the same code, you calculate the point on the circle circumference given radius and angle, then you offset the calculated point by the object position

Comment: Thank @LearnCocos2D, could you give example code on Box2d and cocos2d-x? I'm sorry, i'm newbie box2d :)