# Formula to find points on the circumference of a circle, given the center of the circle and the radius

Tags: center, geometry

I am working on code to **find the points on the circumference of a circle**. I **have the center point of the circle and the radius** and I need to draw a circle around it. This will help me define the boundary. Please help me with formula for finding the these points on the circumference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839899/how-do-i-calculate-a-point-on-a-circles-circumferen

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For a circle with origin **(j, k)** and radius ***r***:

x(t) = r cos(t) + j
   y(t) = r sin(t) + k

where you need to run this equation for ***t*** taking values within the range from 0 to 360, then you will get your ***x*** and ***y*** each on the boundary of the circle.

For more information:
http://www.math.com/tables/geometry/circles.htm