# Andengine how to set a circular wall?

Tags: andengine

My physics world needs a circular boundary. How can that be set? Primitive object does not include 'circle'. So can't specify the wall bound directly. Kindly guide.

Comment: you can try physics editor from this link www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor‎.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct support as far as I have tried. But you can do repeated lines around the circumference of circle to generate a circular collision wall.

You can use the following link to generate points that can be used to draw lines. [Formula to find points on the circumference of a circle, given the center of the circle and the radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829621/formula-to-find-points-on-the-circumference-of-a-circle-given-the-center-of-the)