# Centering an image with absolute position (top, left)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, less

I am using parametric equations to position images around a circle ([How do I calculate a point on a circle’s circumference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839899/how-do-i-calculate-a-point-on-a-circles-circumference))

I am doing this in less, using simple math:

```
// x,y position on circumference:
// x = a + r * cos(t)
// y = b + r * sin(t)

.position {
left: @a + ( @r *  cos(@t) );
top: @b + ( @r *  sin(@t) );
}
```

The trouble I have is that this positions the image by the top left corner, not the center of the image, so doesn't account for the visual offset of height and width this has. Trying to adjust by height/2, width/2 doesn't work as the angle of each image is different.

Is there an easy way to position an image this way so it is centred on x,y?

Comment: If I have misunderstood what you are seeking to do in my answer, please let me know. I've had one down vote (not sure why), so I want to be sure I understood what you were asking correctly. I believe you are trying to center images on their centers around the circumference of some circle, positioned at some angle reference around that circle. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
.position {
    left: @a + ( @r *  cos(@t) );
    top: @b + ( @r *  sin(@t) );

    margin-left: -@r;
    margin-top: -@r;
}
```

Instead of calculations you simply could have done this though:

```
top:50%;
left:50%; 
position:absolute; 

margin-left:-@r;
margin-top:-@r;
```

***[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4x5YL/)***

Comment: Thanks, this is incorrect though. It simply adds a margin equivalent to the radius on both axis.

Comment: @alias51 Apologies, it should be `-@r`

Answer (score -1):

### Subtracting Out Half-Width/Height Does Work

You stated you tried half-width/height calculations in your attempt **to center the image on the circumference of a circle at some angular reference** (as I understand your question). It seems that should and does work. Check out this...

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4x5YL/6/)**

The circle and image colors are for visual reference, but the image positioning is done by:

**LESS**

```css
//define circle position
@r: 100px;
@x: 175px;
@y: 150px;
.setImage(@w, @h, @a) {
    //@a is angle from HORIZONTAL but moves clockwise 
    //(based on radians unless units are given)
    width: @w;
    height: @h;
    left: (@x + ( @r *  cos(@a) ) - (@w / 2));
    top: (@y + ( @r *  sin(@a) ) - (@h / 2));
}
.test1 {
  .setImage(40px, 40px, -35deg);
}
.test2 {
  .setImage(60px, 30px, -80deg);
}
.test3 {
  .setImage(90px, 20px, -150deg);
}
.test4 {
  .setImage(40px, 70px, -240deg);
}
.test5 {
  .setImage(20px, 90px, -295deg);
}
```

**CSS Output**

```css
.test1 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 236.9152044288992px;
  top: 72.64235636489539px;
}
.test2 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 162.36481776669305px;
  top: 36.5192246987792px;
}
.test3 {
  width: 90px;
  height: 20px;
  left: 43.39745962155612px;
  top: 90px;
}
.test4 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 70px;
  left: 104.99999999999996px;
  top: 201.60254037844385px;
}
.test5 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 90px;
  left: 207.26182617406997px;
  top: 195.630778703665px;
}
```

**Works Even With Rotated Images**

Assuming you set your images to have `transform-origin: center center` then it works to keep them on center even if the images are rotated at some angle.

**[See Rotated Image Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4x5YL/7/)**