# SVG - Create a path to join midpoints of group of circles and further extend till circumference points of first & last circle

Tags: d3.js, svg, snap.svg

I am trying to create a path as described in the title for a group of circles given their origin (x,y) and radius. Forming the path with points at origin co-ordinates gives a line joining midpoints as per the alignment of circles, but i want to extend to points further till they overlap with the circumferences of the first and last circle in the group. My intention here is to create a masking path for a set of circles.

What I have:
http://codepen.io/pri315/pen/JGXwEY

```
<path d="M 311.247 144.32 L 315.063 135.925 L 318.726 127.53 L 322.542 119.287Z" />
  <circle id="O_8_6" cx="311.247" cy="144.32" r="3.816"></circle>
  <circle id="O_8_7" cx="315.063" cy="135.925" r="3.816"></circle>
  <circle id="O_8_8" cx="318.726" cy="127.53" r="3.816"></circle>
  <circle id="O_8_9" cx="322.542" cy="119.287" r="3.816"></circle>
```

What I am trying to achieve:
http://codepen.io/pri315/pen/xZVmgG

```
  <path d="M 307.431 151.136 L 315.063 135.925 L 318.726 127.53 L 325.542 114.287" />
  <circle id="O_8_6" cx="311.247" cy="144.32" r="3.816"></circle>
  <circle id="O_8_7" cx="315.063" cy="135.925" r="3.816"></circle>
  <circle id="O_8_8" cx="318.726" cy="127.53" r="3.816"></circle>
  <circle id="O_8_9" cx="322.542" cy="119.287" r="3.816"></circle>
```

Note: Above, I have manually configured the path points for representation purpose, But I am looking for a way to programmatically derive the path points for any linear arrangement of circles.

Another [SOF question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839899/how-do-i-calculate-a-point-on-a-circle-s-circumference), points how to  derive the point on circumference of a given circle's radius and origin for an angle, but in my case the angle depends on the arrangement of the circle group, which i am unable to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the inbuilt d3 convex hull algorithm:

```
//make some points
var data = [[140,130],[140,150],[140,180], [150,250]];
//radius of the circle
var radius = 5;
//make svg
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 500).attr("height", 600).append("g");
//make as many circle as many data points
var circleEnter = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter().append("circle").attr("cy", function(d) {
  return d[1]
}).attr("cx", function(d) {
  return d[0]
}).attr("r", function(d) {
  return radius;
}).style("fill", "steelblue");
//the inbuilt convex hull algo to get the path
var hull = svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "hull");
//make the d attribute depending on the algo
hull.datum(d3.geom.hull(data)).attr("d", function(d) { return "M" + d.join("L") + "Z"; });
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/1unburq6/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Works well. I just modified the style a bit by removing "Z" in the path's attribute and adding the "stroke-linecap: square; stroke-linejoin: bevel;" css style to give it a rectangular finish.