# How to get point (on) of any curved line

Tags: android, canvas, draw

I want something like this as in below image

[image]

I created a curved line through canvas.but now i am not getting how will get co-ordinates for circle. and if it can be done by arc then explain how.how much I done

[image]

What I have tried is below:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    PointF curvePoint = new PointF(580, 120); //curve point
    PointF mPoint2 = new PointF(60, 700); //Last point

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
    paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);


    Path myPath1 = drawCurve(curvePoint, mPoint2);
    canvas.drawPath(myPath1, paint);

}

private Path drawCurve(PointF mPointa, PointF mPointb) {

    Path myPath = new Path();
    myPath.moveTo(600, 60);  // starting point

    myPath.quadTo(mPointa.x, mPointa.y, mPointb.x, mPointb.y);

    return myPath;
}
```

Please help !

Comment: You curve appears to be a circle segment (arc). If you know the center and the radius length (and the angle), then it's just about applying trigonometry.

Comment: by trignomentry how can i find the point on arc?? @HrundiV.Bakshi

Comment: read `android.graphics.PathMeasure` documentation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/839931/2649012

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi  how will draw arc with center and radius??

Comment: just use your `Path`as it is, whats wrong with it?

Comment: @pskink i also want that circle on that curve

Comment: then read `android.graphics.PathMeasure` documentation

Comment: @pskink how will i use this?

Comment: call `PathMeasure#getPosTan` several (8) times

Comment: @pskink can you explain more

Comment: if you have 8 circles to draw you need to call `getPosTan` 8 times, each time increasing the `distance` accordingly

Comment: getPostTan is just returning boolean. on this basis how will it done? @pskink

Comment: did you read `getPostTan` documentation? what are `distance` and `pos` parameters for?

Comment: @pskink i didn't get that circle on that curve line now. i want to add them.

Comment: `i didn't get that circle on that curve line now` what do you mean?

Comment: @pskink see the question once again

Comment: so draw the circle: `Canvas#drawCircle`

Comment: but how will set this circle to accurate position?? on curve line

Comment: just try `PathMeasure#getPosTan`

Comment: it is not giving  the position... well i am too much confused right now. can you please show some demo example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a point on a quadratic bezier curve.

```
private PointF getPointOnQuad(PointF p1, PointF p2, PointF p3, float p){    
        float x1 = (p2.x - p1.x) * p + p1.x;
        float y1 = (p2.y - p1.y) * p + p1.y;
        float x2 = (p3.x - p2.x) * p + p2.x;
        float y2 = (p3.y - p2.y) * p + p2.y;
        PointF point = new PointF((x2 - x1) * p + x1, (y2 - y1) * p + y1);        
        return point;
}
```

Returns the point that is `p = 0 to 1` along the curve `p1`, `p2`, `p3`. Where `p = 0` is the start of the curve, `p = 0.5` is midway and `p = 1` is the end. The points `p1` is the start, `p2` is the control point, and `p3` is the end.

For your curve to get the midpoint,

```
PointF pointOnCurve = getPointOnQuad(new PointF(600,60), mPointa, mPointb, 0.5);
```