# How can i make a circular motion in javascript

Tags: javascript, khan-academy

I'm trying to make the Solar System using javascript, and I'm using khan academy to make it, but i don't know how can i make them move in a circle around the Sun
I kept browsing the net for hours, but i couldn't find anything. Here's my project so that you can see what i have done and what can you do in it

https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/solar-system/6120244512161792

Comment: Have you done any trigonometry before?

Comment: actually no, but you can check my project and see if you can do anything in it and then send to me a link of my project as a Spin-off

Comment: Please share with us the code you have tried so far.

Comment: I think you would do better to ask a more specific question.

Comment: guys check the link i put in the post

Comment: @Vini.g.fer https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/solar-system/6120244512161792

Comment: Judging by the code in your project, you really need to go through the Khan programming missions before continuing. You currently hard-code every position for every planet in the drawing functions, etc. So you can't animate them at all. Learn about variables, objects, arrays, functions and loops. Then you can put your data for each planet in an object and these objects in an array. And then you can loop through the array, drawing each object and changing their positional data for the animation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to get you started:

```js
x = 100  // center
y = 50   // center
r = 50   // radius
a = 0    // angle (from 0 to Math.PI * 2)

function rotate(a) {
  
  var px = x + r * Math.cos(a); // <-- that's the maths you need
  var py = y + r * Math.sin(a);
  
  document.querySelector('#point').style.left = px + "px";
  document.querySelector('#point').style.top = py + "px";  
}


setInterval(function() {
  a = (a + Math.PI / 360) % (Math.PI * 2);
  rotate(a);
}, 5);
```

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

#center {
  left: 100px;
  top: 50px;
  background: black;
}

#point {
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="center"></div>
<div id="point"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks but can you check if it can work in khan academy and if it works tell me, but if it doesnt work then try to modify it please

Comment: @CGUltimateno: Surely the math will work if whatever you're using supports standard JavaScript. Math is the same everywhere...

Comment: In Khan academy don't use `Math.`, just use `cos`, `sin` and `PI` directly

Comment: @CGUltimateno, just look at the code provided, it won't work by copying and pasting it. It'll just show you an example of how to compute the x and y of the thing rotating. A hint would be that "a" is the angle, x,y are the the coordinates of the center, px and py are the coordinates of the thing rotating.

Answer (score 0):

See the other animation lessons in Khan academy. The `draw()` function automatically repeatedly runs to create an animation.

So you need to change a value(s) in the `draw()` function to make something move. To start with you'll probably want to to look at the [equations of a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839899/how-do-i-calculate-a-point-on-a-circle-s-circumference) and do something with that.

Here's a [spin-off](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/spin-off-of-solar-system/2939740662) you can look at.

Comment: I feel like the spin-off is a little too much help.

Comment: I know. I have a bad cold and I'm bored

Comment: There's always hackerrank.com

Comment: I'm expecting to see an update from the OP to scale, with all the orbits correctly calculated and including sattelites

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that will work on khan academy:

```
var x = 100;
var y = 100;
draw= function() {
    background(255, 0, 0);
    x=100*cos(frameCount);
    y=100*sin(frameCount);
    ellipse(x,y,20,20);
};
```

It will draw an ellipse that "orbits" around the origin.. hopefully you can take the basic demonstration of the trig, and extrapolate to fit your needs.