# d3.js pie chart clock

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Using d3.js - I would like to create this kind of clock interface.

Ideally if there is a way to incorporate a 12 clock data driven way into this pie chart.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/qkHK6/2191/

```
var w = 400;
var h = 400;
var r = h / 2;
var color = d3.scale.category20c();

var data = [{
  "label": "Category B",
  "value": 70
}, {
  "label": "Category A",
  "value": 30
}];


var vis = d3.select('#chart').append("svg:svg").data([data]).attr("width", w).attr("height", h).append("svg:g").attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")");
var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d) {
  return d.value;
});

// declare an arc generator function
var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r);

// select paths, use arc generator to draw
var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice").data(pie).enter().append("svg:g").attr("class", "slice");
arcs.append("svg:path")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    // log the result of the arc generator to show how cool it is :)
    console.log(arc(d));
    return arc(d);
  });
```

Comment: be great to make it responsive too at some point - http://jsfiddle.net/RodEsp/fdzbv6vg/

Comment: -- here is a simple clock face. http://jsfiddle.net/c9jorqje/6/  -- how do I add the ticks, and a pie chart range underneath that shows the time range?

Comment: What does the pie range exactly mean in the clock face?

Comment: I think the slice is to start at the 9am point and then end at 6pm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is no magic bullet for this case. But, you can accomplish the goal with some mathematics.

jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3uz3nzpx/2/) in advance.

### Ticks

Ticks can be drawn based on [trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions). If you are scared about tons of formulas, just take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/839931/4751310) and use them. He described it  very neatly as pseudo-code (I guess).

```
var radius = 80;
var tickLength = 10;
var circleDegree = 360;

clockGroup.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'ticks')
  .selectAll('path')
  .data(splitDegrees(12))
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', function(d) {
    var coord = {
      outer: getCoordFromCircle(d, 0, 0, radius),
      inner: getCoordFromCircle(d, 0, 0, radius - tickLength)
    };
    return 'M' + coord.outer[0] + ' ' + coord.outer[1] + 'L' + coord.inner[0] + ' ' + coord.inner[1] + 'Z';
  });

function degToRad(degrees) {
  return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}

// it'll give you xy-coord by degree from 12(or 0) o'clock 
function getCoordFromCircle(deg, cx, cy, r) {
  var rad = degToRad(deg);
  var x = cx + r * Math.cos(rad);
  var y = cy + r * Math.sin(rad);
  return [x, y];
}

function splitDegrees(num) {
  var angle = circleDegree / num;
  var degrees = [];

  for (var ang = 0; ang < circleDegree; ang += angle) {
    degrees.push(ang);
  }

  return degrees;
}
```

### Arc range

In this case, you can draw it via simple [d3 methods](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Shapes.md#arc).

```
var fromClock = 9;
var toClock = 6;

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(0)
  .outerRadius(radius)
  .startAngle(clockToRad(fromClock, -1))
  .endAngle(clockToRad(toClock, 1));

clockGroup.append('path')
  .attr('d', arc)
  .style('fill', 'orange');

function clockToRad(clock, direction) {
  var unit = circleDegree / 12;
  var degree = direction > 0 ? unit * clock : unit * clock - circleDegree;
  return degToRad(degree);
}
```

Comment: that is great man. I've tweaked it to make it look more like their designs. http://jsfiddle.net/3uz3nzpx/3/ -- I don't know if they would anticipate it to be an actual clock -- but thought this was a start. Is there a way to LOCK the clock to the start time?

Comment: @TheOldCounty you don't want the clock to be animated?

Comment: @TheOldCounty If it was right, you just turn off `setInterval` function and change `startAngle` and `endAngle` of `minuteArc` and `hourArc` to what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/jkiimm/3uz3nzpx/4/

Comment: Well not too sure - was looking for options -- what is the start and end time are not bang on 9, 6 -- what if the start time was 9:20

Comment: I've added a fraction element to the time -- so you can add a time and have it be 1/2 an hour. http://jsfiddle.net/3uz3nzpx/5/

Comment: @TheOldCounty great update. it is working about any time.

Comment: Actually I noticed the minute hand is broken -- when its 9:30 --- the minute hand is still stuck at 0.  http://jsfiddle.net/3uz3nzpx/7/

Comment: were you able to fix the clock?

Comment: @TheOldCounty I haven't enough time to fix it recently but, I made time a little bit. I've updated your fiddle and tried to reuse some functions instead of huge refactoring. `scale` functions are already made and you could expand usage of them. http://jsfiddle.net/3uz3nzpx/8/

Comment: Where is the wrong? Isn't it right the orange arc area is drawn on between 9:15 - 18:00?