# THREE.js How to calculate rotation position on a 3D circle?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, rotation, cannon.js

As represented in the image below, I have a `THREE.Scene` with a simple cube. Attached to the cube is a `CANNON.Body` for Physics (represented in the green wireframe).

The `CANNON.Body` is offset from the cube by a couple of units. For rotation, this offset will be the **radius**.

When I rotate the cube, I want the `CANNON.Body` to rotate around the cube based on the **angle** and **radius**. On the right hand side of the image, I rotated the cube with an **angle** of 45 degrees (I also have radians available). However, the `CANNON.Body` does not rotate *around* the cube, only around it's own center. I need it to rotate *around* the cube for all axes **x**, **y** and **z**.

Is there a built-in function in `THREE.js` or should I use my own mathematical equation for this? If so, what would that be?

[image]

Thanks!

*P.S. I've seen solutions for pure `THREE.js` Scene's where the geometry is translated to manipulate the pivot point. Since I don't have geometry in my `CANNON.Body`, this will not be possible.*

Comment: One way might be to add an (otherwise empty) `Object3D` to the scene, but leave its position at the center of rotation. Add the `CANNON.Body` not to the scene but to that `Object3D`. Move the `CANNON.Body` as you did before to shift it, and instead rotate the `Object3D`.

Comment: @Leeft Thank you for the suggestion. However, I want to try and not add unnecessary Objects to the Scene. I know that this can be solved mathematically, I just don't know how to apply it to my situation and what equations to use. If you have any other suggestions, please let me know!

Comment: Other possible options I can think of: move the pivot point, or [do the math yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/839931/3755747) (there's no builtin function, but `THREE.Math` has some `radToDeg` and `degToRad` helpers). There's nothing wrong with creating some (otherwise empty) `Object3D` to group or offset things in your scene though, and in fact the scene itself is essentially an `Object3D` which has several `Object3D` as its children (such as your lights, objects, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with cannonjs, but was it possible to just add the Cube and the Rigid Body in a Three.Group?

Like

```
var rigidBody = new CANNON.Body(); // whatever it is for cannon
var model = new THREE.Group();

// your model goes here
model.add(new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1), 
  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial()
));

model.add(rigidBody);
scene.add(model);
```

This way, if you rotate the parent element *model*, the rigidbody should update the same way.