# Curved Shape Background Header in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a list view with "Hero" icons on the left. When I click a list item, it loads the next screen with the article text and the Hero image (which animates nicely/automatically to the correct spot on the 2nd screen).

I would have thought that was the "tough" part, but I'm now trying to get a curved shape as the top background of the 2nd screen. I would love to make it a drawn vector shape, as opposed to a bitmap and even have it drip/bounce onto the page, but at the moment...

**I'm just trying to figure out how to:**

1. draw a vector shape
2. have it as the background of a screen with other widgets on top (see purple curve on 2nd screen below)

[image: goal]

Comment: [This](https://iirokrankka.com/2017/09/04/clipping-widgets-with-bezier-curves-in-flutter/) might help you.

Comment: @JeromeEscalante I don't think it should require masking off an image or a block of color. (should it?)  I think there's a way to create a shape with flutter.

Comment: Flutter has full blown Canvas, and Path classes  if you want a lower level control  instead of ClipPath solution

Comment: `"I think there's a way to create a shape with flutter."` - see `ShapeBorder` class (or use `CustomPaint` to have the full control on what you want to draw)

Comment: @pskink I saw this class, but couldn't find any reasonable examples to follow or learn. :/

Comment: `ShapeBorder`? or `CustomPaint`?

Comment: for using `ShapeBorder` see https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Material/shape.html

Comment: @pskink - am I missing something? That page has almost no helpful information.

Comment: yes, it has: any material widget can have a shape defined by a custom [ShapeBorder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/ShapeBorder-class.html) class - like: BeveledRectangleBorder BoxBorder CircleBorder InputBorder RoundedRectangleBorder StadiumBorder

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I made a full sample for your curved shape in a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/tarek360/c94a82f9554caf8f6b62c4fcf140272f)

I used [CustomPainter](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) to draw on a canvas then, with some geometric calculations, I achieved the curved shape.

**Final result**

[image: Flutter curved shape with a circle inside]

### How I draw it?

[image]

Before coding and on a **Whiteboard** I determined somethings:

1. **My Canvas Area**:

   - The canvas dimensions I need to draw that shape (which equals to Flutter widget's dimensions).
2. **How and where my brush will move**?

   - how means: what are the APIs I need to draw that shape on the canvas using the [Path](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Path-class.html) class.
     e.g. [lineTo()](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Path/lineTo.html) for a straight line, [quadraticBezierTo()](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Path/quadraticBezierTo.html) for a curve.
   - where means: Where are the points (coordinates) I need to draw the whole shape. (see yellow and green dots in the image above)
3. **Points (coordinates) Calculations**:

   - I used some geometric equations to calculate the coordinates. e.g. [Point on a circle’s circumference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/839931/3311219)
   - All of my calculations depend on the canvas size, that gives me a responsive shape.

[Full sample here!](https://gist.github.com/tarek360/c94a82f9554caf8f6b62c4fcf140272f)

Comment: Works wonderfully AND serves as a great example as a learning exercise! Thanks!