# Point SVG shape in a direction around a circle

Tags: java, processing

**What I'm trying to do:**
Create a compass when given a direction in degrees (0 - 360). Like so:

[image: Compass]

**What I have done:**
I have managed to get the SVG image to point in the right direction but I can't seem to get it to rotate around the circle. To attempt a solution around the circle, I have decided to try get the positioning using the ellipse tool and [this formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839899/how-do-i-calculate-a-point-on-a-circle-s-circumference). This is what it looks like at the moment:

[image: Current]

(notice how the arrow faces a different direction to the ellipse, in the circle, on the axis - given the center point is the middle of the green circle)

```
void setDirection(float value, int radius) {
  fill(secondaryColour);
  float origin_x = (1280 - (width-400)/2);
  float origin_y = height/2;
  float x = origin_x + radius * cos(radians(value));
  float y = origin_y +radius * sin(radians(value));

  //grey circle
  ellipse(x, y, 20, 20);
  
  //arrow SVG
  pushMatrix();
  translate(200, 300);
  rotate(radians(value));
  scale(0.5);
  shape(arrow);
  popMatrix();
}
```

Please note: `value` is in degrees and `radius` is the radius I want the arrow to sit on. What am I doing wrong with the ellipse? and how can I bring them both together?

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but why the 300 in `translate(200, 300);` ?

Comment: @laancelot - the translate helped move the arrow into a position, rather than it sitting on the top left.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I found that the starting angle started on the white line, but I was assuming it would start on the red (similar to the angle of the arrow). To resolve the issue I needed to subtract 90 degrees from the variable `value` before converting it into radians.